# SQL find all duplicates in a table, remove them, and update foreign key in linked table

Tags: sql, db2, toad

I have 2 tables, a `PROMOTION` table and a `PRIZE` table. The `PRIZE` table contains a primary key `PRIZEID`, as well as two other fields: `COST` and `PRIZENAME`. The `PROMOTION` table contains several fields as well as the foreign key `PRIZEID` which links the two tables together.

Right now my `PRIZE` table contains duplicate entries (a duplicate would be any rows that have identical cost and prizename). What I want to do is to find all duplicates in the `PRIZE` table, remove all duplicates (essentially leaving one unique row for each cost-prizename pair) and have the foreign keys updated in the `PROMOTION` table to reflect these changes.

So for instance, in my prize table I have

```
prizeid             cost             prizename
1                   100                TV
2                    50                Computer
3                   100                TV
4                    50                Computer
5                    200               Book
```

and the promotion table contains row like

```
promotionid ...  prizeid
1                  1
2                  3
3                  2
```

I want the prize table to end up looking like this

```
prizeid             cost             prizename
1                   100                TV
2                    50                Computer
5                    200               Book
```

and the promotion table to look like

```
promotionid ...  prizeid
1                  1
2                  1
3                  2
```

I am not entirely sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to do it in two steps:

(1) First, you will need to update all the entries in the `PROMOTION table` that points to a row that will be deleted to the equivalent row.

```
UPDATE promotion p SET 
    prizeid = 
        (SELECT prizeid FROM prize 
            WHERE 
                cost = (SELECT cost FROM prize WHERE prizeid = p.prizeid) 
            AND 
                prizename = (SELECT prizename FROM prize WHERE prizeid = p.prizeid) 
            ORDER BY prizeid ASC LIMIT 1
        );
```

(2) And then, delete all the duplicated rows from the `PRIZE table`.

```
DELETE FROM prize 
    WHERE prizeid NOT IN 
        (SELECT tab.pi FROM 
            (SELECT DISTINCT prizeid AS pi FROM prize GROUP BY prizename, cost)
        AS tab);
```

One way to prevent this from happening again is to make the `cost` and `prizename` be the PRIMARY KEY, instead of the `prizeid`.

Comment: You don't really need to change the primary key -- I'd rather declare an additional unique constraint on (cost, prizename).

Comment: That's one way. I didn't really mean it's the only way. I agree with your solution too.

Comment: For part 1, how would I update the `prizeIds` in the `promotion table` to be one of the `prizeIds` from the `prize table` for a group of duplicates?

Comment: Check the edited answer with the part 1 code. I don't know if that's what you really want, but it's what I understood from you question. I'm still trying the part 2, but I'm kinda out of time right now.

Comment: @Mike, check if it is what you were looking for. I think it's done now.

Comment: @LucasHarada won't the first query update all the rows in the promotion table?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you only want to retain the first instance of every cost + PrizeName combination. You could use this:

```
UPDATE Promotion
SET PrizeId = A.FirstPrizeIdPerCostPrizeNameCombination

FROM
    Promotion AS P 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
        PrizeId, Cost, PrizeName,
        [FirstPrizeIdPerCostPrizeNameCombination] = First_Value(PrizeId) OVER (PARTITION BY Cost,PrizeName ORDER BY PrizeId)
    FROM
        Prize
    ) AS A ON A.PrizeId = P.PrizeId
```